# How do I compare two lists of diffrent sizes, find matches and return the indices of those matches in both lists

Tags: python

In pygame I am building a GA simulation. The simulation involves 10 creatures and 100 pieces of food. I am creating them as sprites. I tried to use built in sprite collision detection but I need to detect collisions between unique sprites, not sprites and groups or groups and groups. That led me to realize I need a custom solution. Since my numbers are low I figured I could throw the positions of the food and creatures into lists and compare them. That part works but what I can't figure out is how to get the inidices for the matches in the lists. I'm not too worried about speed because I think my comparison is fast enough, especially given the small amount of data involved and the relative rarity of collisions but I'd still like an inexpensive solution to find those indices. I could create dictionaries, etc. I'm not sure what's the best route. My test code for the comparison is below, and working great and gives me half of my answer, the indices of the bots making the collisions. All I need now is the indices of the food collided with.

```
from random import *
food = [(randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 1000)) for i in range(100)]
while True:
    bots = [(randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 1000)) for i in range(10)]
    for i in range(len(bots)):
        if bots[i] in food:
            print(i, bots[i])
    for i in range(len(food)):
        if food[i] in bots:
            print(i, food[i])
```

The above code does precisely what I want but is a dirty bodge and extremely expensive. It gets me going for now but it will have to be refined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For food, use dictionary instead of list....

```
from random import randint

food = {i:(randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 1000)) for i in range(100)}
while True:
    
    bots = [(randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 1000)) for i in range(10)]
    for i in range(len(bots)):
        if bots[i] in food.values():
            
            print(f'Bot num {i} collided with food num {list(food.keys())[list(food.values()).index(bots[i])]}')
            # "list(food.keys())[list(food.values()).index(bots[i])]" finds the key of the given value (here, the bot position)
```

Output:

```
Bot num 3 collided with food num 80
Bot num 6 collided with food num 51
Bot num 3 collided with food num 32
Bot num 8 collided with food num 86
Bot num 7 collided with food num 98
Bot num 9 collided with food num 94
Bot num 5 collided with food num 88
```

This continues till I stop.

Comment: You added the EXACT comments I removed from my code befor posting it. It's uncanny.  "# bots are moving constantly", "# feed the bot, pop the food from the list and kill the object, etc..." I'm looking at my editor window and it's spooky how you did that.

Comment: @Dave That's because i copied the code, edited then pasted but didn't notice the comment was removed. Sorry...

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I would have gotten there today but probably very late at night. Now I can sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a concrete answer because I don't know what a GA simulation is. Genetic Algorithm? Is it 2d, 3d, nd? The approach for any of them will be similar.

It's probably best to approach this a little differently.

We have a "Location" that contains: it's identifier ie x,y(,z...) coordinates, a value for a bot to exist, and a value for food to exist. Then the primary data structure is a list of all these locations.

Now, for every frame (step/generation/etc), we iterate all possible locations and if the value exists for both food and a bot at any location, we know we have a collision. From there, it's just integrating whatever logic you want for your sim.

Comment: Hi, sorry, it's a 2d sim on a 1000 x 1000 screen and what you're describing is exactly what I'm trying to do, I think. Get the locations into lists and check for matches between the two lists. If there is a match, I have a collision and can make the necesary changes. A sort of a bodgy way to do it is to simply do the comparison again, but in the other direction, but that's SO expensive. I think I'll try that for now just so I can forge ahead with other problems on my list.